# Как работает деинсталятор?

Tags: c#, c++, windows

Пишу деинсталятор.

Допустим, он запускается, удаляет все файлы, а, в конечном итоге, он должен удалить сам себя. Но процесс держит EXE-файл. Как быть?

Answer (score 24):

[`MoveFileEx()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/aa365240(v=vs.85).aspx) с флагом `MOVEFILE_DELAY_UNTIL_REBOOT`. Тогда ваш файл удалится после перезагрузки. И не надо будет с батниками плясать.

Comment: А решение на шарпе сможете накидать? Мне тоже интересно, обычно батником обходился.

Comment: @Monk не смогу, потому что на нем не пишу. Вызов этой API на сях, если путь к файлу известен и без проверок результата - одна строка.

Comment: @Monk http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32/MoveFileEx.html, коды флагов смотреть тут https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/aa365240(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @Monk, надо просто msi обходиться, тогда и батники не понадобятся ;)

Comment: @ixSci ну или NSIS.

Comment: А без перезагрузки?

Comment: @Qwertiy а без ерезагрузки - это надо соответствующего троя найти и посмотреть как там сделано. Обычно, конечно, через cmd.exe делается...

Comment: _"и без проверок результата"_ - а что-то может пойти не так? Он же просто куда-то запишет, что файл удалить надо и всё?

Answer (score 1):

На всякий случай, вариант через CMD (команда `ping 127.0.0.1 -n 5 > nul` нужна для задержки в пять секунд):

```
Process.Start("cmd.exe", "/C ping 127.0.0.1 -n 5 > nul & del " + 
      Application.ExecutablePath); 
Application.Exit();
```

Ещё, как вариант, можно создать и запустить простенький bat-файл — они могут удалять сами себя без проблем.